# adding a primary key when a foreign key already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, mysql-workbench

I need to add a primary key on a table "usernames"

I have 3 columns in it :

```
userid int(10)
username char(20)
user char(50)
```

and the primary key is set on 'username' field and i used it as a foreign key to link it to another table. Now i need to add primary key on 'userid' field also... so i tried out :

```
alter table `usernames` drop primary key, add primary key(userid,username);
```

and i get an error saying

```
ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'PRIMARY":needed in a foreign key constraint
```

is there any possible way to do this ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is:

1. Drop the FK constraint
2. Drop PK Constraint
3. Create New PK
4. Add Unique Constraint on the name column
5. Recreate FK

Raj

Comment: Best to script out the fk before you drop it, so that it is easier to recreate!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use MySql (despite you tag your question as Sql Server).

You can decide to:

Disable all check and try to remove primary key but the new must have the same name

or

Drop foreign key constraints referred to your primary key and then remove your primary key and finally re-add foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the foreign key in order to modify the primary key

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the name, a table can only have at most *one* `PRIMARY` key.  Whilst it can have other `UNIQUE` keys, which have a similar effect, they really ought not be used for foreign-key relations.

So, you have two choices:

- Retain your existing schema (perhaps `username` is a perfectly good natural key such that you need not bother with a synthetic one, in which case you can consider dropping the `userid` column altogether); or
- Making `userid` your `PRIMARY` key, in which case `username` should not be used for foreign key relations.  I outline below a method for doing this "offline" (where the database is guaranteed not to be altered by any other process during the transition); should you be working "online", you will need to add further steps to ensure integrity is preserved:

  1. Add a new `userid` column for the foreign key in all child tables and drop the existing foreign key constraint:

     ```
     ALTER TABLE foo
       ADD COLUMN userid INT(10),
       DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name;
     ```
  2. Change the primary key in your `usernames` tables (should you wish for the database to enforce a uniqueness constraint over `username`, you can define a `UNIQUE` key instead):

     ```
     ALTER TABLE usernames
       DROP PRIMARY KEY,
       ADD  PRIMARY KEY (userid),
       ADD  UNIQUE  KEY (username);  -- optional
     ```
  3. Update the child tables to contain the relevant `userid` from the parent:

     ```
     UPDATE foo JOIN usernames USING (username)
       SET foo.userid = usernames.userid;
     ```
  4. Add the new foreign key constraints and drop the old `username` columns from the child tables:

     ```
     ALTER TABLE foo
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES usernames (userid),
       DROP COLUMN username;
     ```